PLS-00201 error. Identified must be declared
I'm learning PL/SQL and am trying to execute this example code. When I try to do that, I get PLS-0021 error. Can you please advice me how to correct this? Thank you!
Error:
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 2, column 14:
PLS-00201: identifier '<schema>.<table>' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated

Code:
DECLARE
    v_serial <schema>.<table>%TYPE;
BEGIN
    select serial
        into v_serial
    from <schema>.<table>;
END;


Where did you get that code? Looks like <schema> and <table> are "place holders". You probably need to replace them with an actual schema name and an actual table name.

%TYPE is for referencing a column type, not a row type. Either add the column name to your variable definition, or use %ROWTYPE instead.
For example:
drop table test_table;
create table test_table(serial number);
insert into test_table values(1);

declare
    v_serial test_table.serial%type;
begin
    select serial
    into v_serial
    from test_table;
end;
/

Because of the error message you're seeing, I think there are other problems with your code. But those errors are perhaps related to how you are using a template or placeholder values. I didn't include the schema name in my example so that I could post a fully reproducible example. Once you get the above code working, then you can work on adding the schema name in front of the table name.
